# Index of an element in an array in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to find a way to get an index of an element in an array that partially matches a certain patten.
Let's say I have an array with values

```
Maria likes tomatoes,
Sonia likes plums,
Andrew likes oranges
```

If my search term is plums, I will get 1 returned as index.
Thank you!

Comment: Iterate over the array and use pattern matching to find if yourstring matches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick search didn't find a dupe, but I'm sure there is one.  Meanwhile:

To find elements of an array that meet a certain condition, you use `grep`.  If you want the indexes instead of the elements.. well, Perl 6 added a `grep-index` method to handle that case, but in Perl 5 the easiest way is to change the target of `grep`. That is, instead of running it on the original array, run it on a list of indexes - just with a condition that references the original array.  In your case, that might look like this:

```
my @array = ( 'Maria likes tomatoes', 
              'Sonia likes plums', 
              'Andrew likes oranges');

grep { $array[$_] =~ /plums/ } 0..$#array;    # 1
```

Relevant bits:

- `$#array` returns the index of the last element of `@array`.
- *m*`..`*n* generates a range of values between *m* and *n* (inclusive); in list context that becomes a list of those values.
- `grep {` *code* `}` *list* returns the elements of *list* for which *code* produces a true value when the special variable `$_` is set to the element.

These sorts of expressions read most easily from right to left. So, first we generate a list of all the indexes of the original array (`0..$#array`), then we use `grep` to test each index (represented by `$_`) to see if the corresponding element of `@array` (`$array[$_]`) matches (`~=`) the regular expression `/plums/`.

If it does, that index is included in the list returned by the `grep`; if not, it's left out. So the end result is a list of only those indexes for which the condition is true.  In this case, that list contains only the value 1.

**Added to reply to your comment:** It's important to note that the return value of `grep` is normally a *list* of matching elements, even if there is only one match.  If you assign the result to an array (e.g. with `my @indexes = grep`...), the array will contain all the matching values.  However, `grep` is context-sensitive, and if you call it in scalar context (e.g. by assigning its return value to a scalar variable with something like `my $count = grep`...), you'll instead only get a number telling you how many matches there were.  You might want to take a look at [this tutorial](http://perlmaven.com/scalar-and-list-context-in-perl) on context sensitivity in Perl.

Comment: Thank you, Mark! While when printing I get the correct value with this code, I can't store it. If I assign it to a variable I get 1 as a result, regardless of what the index is. Do you know what problem is at hand here?

Comment: grep will be returning a list, so if you have multiple hits, you'll get multiple results. You can assign it with `my @indicies = grep ....`.

Comment: @MarkReed: *“The return value of grep is a list of matching elements ...”* That's not really true. A *list* in scalar context evaluates to the last element of the list. It is `grep` itself that is contexts sensitive, and returns a count of matching elements in scalar context. That is different from a subroutine that always returns a list.

Comment: @Sobrique - Even better would be to use [`first`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util#first) from the core `List::Util` module because it short-circuits on finding item:  `my $first_match = first { ...`

Answer (score 3):

This is what `firstidx` from [List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils) is for.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use List::MoreUtils 'firstidx';

my @array = ('Maria likes tomatoes',
             'Sonia likes plums',
             'Andrew likes oranges');

say firstidx { /plums/ } @array;
```

**Update:** I see that draegtun has answered your comment about getting multiple indexes. But I wonder why you couldn't just browse the List::MoreUtils documentation to see if there was a useful-looking function in there.

Comment: What if you want the indexes of all the matching elements, not just the first (or last, since `List::MoreUtils` also offers `lastidx`)?

Comment: @MarkReed - see `indexes` in `List::MoreUtils` to get indexes of all matching elements - https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils#indexes-BLOCK-LIST